# Undetected_chromedriver is detected Python (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am using selenium for loggin into the site and I decided to use undetected_chromedriver library. Everything was good, but after few tests, site detected me and I can`t make a loggin.

But if I change a version of undetected_chromedriver it will work (doesn`t matter which version will be, latest or old), but not a long time and after this I have to change undetected_chromedriver version again.

I have this options:

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument('--disable-features=TranslateUI')
options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs",
    {
        "credentials_enable_service": False,
        "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US',
    },
)
```

```
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
```

And I don`t use a basic window size. I also tried to change selenium versions, but it doesn't work. I have Python v.3.7 and Chromedriver v107. I will be grateful if someone knows how to solve this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: target website is probably profiling your requests and blocking them as they seem unnatural. First thing to do is change IP address and check if problem persists. Plus - chrome v.107 is relatively new and not much people use it, which makes your fingerprint more unique. Check  https://amiunique.org/fp for analyzing your fp

Comment: What's your target website?